# using user defined Gjs classes in looking glass

Tags: gnome, looking-glass

when defining Gjs classes within the scope of an extension, Because they can be assigned to a variable for later usage, there is a handle (namely the variable they are assigned to) to use them throughout the code.

```js
var myClass = new Lang.Class({Name:'thisClass',...});
var instance = new myClass();
```

but attempting to use these classes that are defined within extensions, within the scope of looking glass, is not possible since there is no global variable assigned to them as a handle that I know of.

they are definitely globally defined since declaring a Gjs class of the same name triggers an error in looking glass.

```js
//the following executed is within the scope of looking glass while an exctension including a class with the same name is running
var myClassLG = new Lang.Class({Name:'thisClass',...});
// returns <exception Error: Type of Gjs_thisClass is already registered.>


var myClassLG = new Lang.Class({Name:'thisClassWithDifferentNameButSameContent',...});
// this works
var instance = new myClassLG();
```

so is there a way to use these classes within the scope of looking glass without having to re-declare them with a different name?